# Swing Graphics color Image directly

Tags: java, swing

Short Question: Is it possible to color an image directly in the graphics2d.drawImage(...) method? I mean not to choose the background color but select a color for every visible pixel on the image.

Comment: It "might" be possible to do it though a `BufferedImageOp` or `BufferedImageFilter`, but, a simply solution would be to use the pixel data directly

Comment: And how to I get the data? Can I turn the image into a shape? That would be helpful.

Comment: [`BufferedImage#getData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getData--) or [`BufferedImage#getRGB`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB-int-int-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of manipulating pixels of a `BufferedImage`.
The example inverts this image

[image]

to negative by manipulating each pixel:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class ShowNegativeImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedImage bImage = getImage("http://www.digitalphotoartistry.com/rose1.jpg");
        image2Negative(bImage);
        displayImage(bImage);
    }

    private static BufferedImage getImage(String path) {

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(path);
            return ImageIO.read(url);

        } catch ( IOException ex) { ex.printStackTrace();}

        return null;
    }

    private static void displayImage(java.awt.Image image){

        ImageIcon icon= new ImageIcon(image);
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JLabel(icon));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void image2Negative(BufferedImage bImage) {

        for (int x = 0; x < bImage.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < bImage.getHeight(); y++) {
                int rgba = bImage.getRGB(x, y);
                Color col = new Color(rgba, true);
                col = new Color(255 - col.getRed(),
                                255 - col.getGreen(),
                                255 - col.getBlue());
                bImage.setRGB(x, y, col.getRGB());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]